# Parameterize select query in unary kdb function

Tags: kdb

I'd like to be able to select rows in batches from a very large keyed table being stored remotely on disk. As a toy example to test my function I set up the following tables `t` and `nt`...

```
t:([sym:110?`A`aa`Abc`B`bb`Bac];px:110?10f;id:1+til 110)
nt:0#t
```

I select from the table only records that begin with the character "A", count the number of characters, divide the count by the number of rows I would like to fetch for each function call (10), and round that up to the nearest whole number...

```
aRec:select from t where sym like "A*"
counter:count aRec
divy:counter%10
divyUP:ceiling divy
```

Next I set an `idx` variable to 0 and write an `if statement` as the parameterized function. This checks if `idx` equals `divyUP`. If not, then it should select the first 10 rows of `aRec`, upsert those to the `nt` table, increment the function argument, `x`, by 10, and increment the `idx` variable by 1. Once the `idx` variable and `divyUP` are equal it should exit the function...

```
idx:0
batches:{[x]if[not idx=divyUP;batch::select[x 10]from aRec;`nt upsert batch;x+:10;idx+::1]}
```

However when I call the function it returns a `type` error...

```
q)batches 0
'type
[1]  batches:{[x]if[not idx=divyUP;batch::select[x 10]from aRec;`nt upsert batch;x+:10;idx+::1]}
                                                 ^
```

I've tried using it with `sublist` too, though I get the same result...

```
batches:{[x]if[not idx=divyUP;batch::x 10 sublist aRec;`nt upsert batch;x+:10;idx+::1]}

q)batches 0
'type
[1]  batches:{[x]if[not idx=divyUP;batch::x 10 sublist aRec;`nt upsert batch;x+:10;idx+::1]}
                                          ^
```

However issuing either of those above commands outside of the function both return the expected results...

```
q)select[0 10] from aRec
sym| px        id
---| ------------
A  | 4.236121  1
A  | 5.932252  3
Abc| 5.473628  5
A  | 0.7014928 7
Abc| 3.503483  8
A  | 8.254616  9
Abc| 4.328712  10
A  | 5.435053  19
A  | 1.014108  22
A  | 1.492811  25

q)0 10 sublist aRec
sym| px        id
---| ------------
A  | 4.236121  1
A  | 5.932252  3
Abc| 5.473628  5
A  | 0.7014928 7
Abc| 3.503483  8
A  | 8.254616  9
Abc| 4.328712  10
A  | 5.435053  19
A  | 1.014108  22
A  | 1.492811  25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your example, select[] and sublist requires a list as an input but your input is not a list. Reason for that is when there is a variable in items(which will form a list), it is no longer considered as a simple list meaning blank(space) cannot be used to separate values. In this case, a semicolon is required.

```
q) x:2
q) (1;x) / (1 2)
```

**Select command:**  Change input to (x;10) to make it work.

```
q) t:([]id:1 2 3; v: 3 4 5)
q) {select[(x;2)] from t} 1
```

```
`id  `v
---------
 2    4
 3    5
```

Another alternative is to use 'i'(index) column:

```
q) {select from t where i within x + 0 2} 1
```

**Sublist Command:** Convert left input of the sublist function to a list (x;10).

```
 q) {(x;2) sublist t}1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the select[] form with variable input like that, instead you can use a functional select shown in https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#912-functional-forms where you input as the 5th argument the rows you want

Hope this helps!

Comment: select[] works with variables. Input should be a list.